# jQuery Backstretch fixed height

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, jquery-backstretch

I've seen a few topics of this on the internet, however none were relevant in solving my problem. I'm currently using the jQuery plugin Backstretch and have successfully implemented it as a background for the whole page. However, I'd like to use it within a div with a fixed height. So rather than taking up the whole page, it sort of acts as an image slider.

I used the documentation off of Backstretch's Github to try and implement it but no luck. The div itself is sectioned off (there's a big white space where it should be) but no image.

Thanks for the help!

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<head>
  <meta charset="utf-8" />
  <title>Home</title>
  <link type="text/css" rel="stylesheet" href="stylesheet.css"/>
  <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="http://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Roboto">
  <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="http://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Crimson+Text">
  <script src="jquery.js"></script>
  <script src="jquery.backstretch.js"></script>
</head>
<body>
  <div class="backstretch">
    <script>
      $(".foo").backstretch("test1.jpg");
    </script>
  </div>

  <div class="container">

      <p>Lorem Ipsum is simply dummy text of the printing and typesetting industry. </p>
      <p>Lorem Ipsum is simply dummy text of the printing and typesetting industry. </p>
      <p>Lorem Ipsum is simply dummy text of the printing and typesetting industry. </p>
      <p>Lorem Ipsum is simply dummy text of the printing and typesetting industry. </p>

  </div>
  </body>
</html>
```

With styles:

```
.backstretch{
 width: 100%;
 height: 500px;
}
```

Comment: Where is the element with class `foo`?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It seems that you're selecting a non-existent element (`.foo`) for use with backstretch.

Instead of this:

```
$(".foo").backstretch("test1.jpg");
```

Try this:

```
$(".backstretch").backstretch("test1.jpg");
```

http://jsfiddle.net/89V38/

Comment: Cant't believe that escaped me.. Thanks so much for the help.